# Primeng Component UI issues

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am working on PrimeNG components. But m having issues with UI display on the web browser.

Right now, I want to display static dropdown. I have took reference from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown). The following code is to display that component.

**HTML File**

```
<h3 class="first">Single</h3>
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" placeholder="Select a City"></p-dropdown>
<p>Selected City: {{selectedCity ? selectedCity.name : 'none'}}</p>
```

**Component File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  cities: SelectItem[];

  selectedCity: string;
  constructor() {
    this.cities = [];
    this.cities.push({ label: 'Select City', value: null });
    this.cities.push({ label: 'New York', value: { id: 1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY' } });
    this.cities.push({ label: 'Rome', value: { id: 2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' } });
    this.cities.push({ label: 'London', value: { id: 3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN' } });
    this.cities.push({ label: 'Istanbul', value: { id: 4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' } });
    this.cities.push({ label: 'Paris', value: { id: 5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' } });

  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

And in Module file, I have imported -

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';


imports: [
DropdownModule
]
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

But when I run project, it is not showing me what they have done in **PrimeNG Dropdown example** instead of that m getting this result

[image]

Can anyone guide or help me solving where I need to do changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you installed the library ? 
If not, use "npm install primeng --save" and try again

Comment: @GiliYaniv Yes, I already have done that .

Comment: how did you create your project?  What version of Angular CLI?

Comment: @MihirB did you added primeng styles in your project ? i think you did't add the primeng style.

Comment: @Chandru nop. I have added one bootstrap css in assets-stylesheet. And I havent add this primeng style. Where do I have to add ?

Comment: check my answer. do like this your porject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this :

**npm install primeng**

```
npm install primeng --save
```

add style inside the .angular-cli.json

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
]
```

**module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        DropdownModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
})
```

Comment: Ok that helped me !